# How do I make Unit Test of ProtocolBuffer to improve coverage?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

There generated some java files according to .proto in my code. How do I make a overall test of messages defined , since many odd classes and methods were generated.

The source code is generated automatically, the unit test code ,I think, can also be done.
All I can find is only cpp project, but I am using Spring framework.

https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/tree/master/src/google/protobuf

All I need is to improve coverage. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is most common not to unit-test generated code but to test it through using it in its intended application.

Comment: Improving coverage for the sake of coverage is just wasted time.